# Resolving a ServiceStack Service and defining content type

Tags: c#, json, servicestack, content-type

I'm currently developing a C# ServiceStack API.

In one of the Services I need to execute another service.  I resolve the service from the Funq container and execute the relevant method but get json returned instead of .net objects.

I understand this is because the original request from the front end was for a content-type of json and the default content type is json.

Is there a way I can resolve the service and execute its methods but receive .net objects instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can execute and delegate to another Service in ServiceStack by using `ResolveService<T>`, e.g:

From inside a ServiceStack Service:

```
using (var service = base.ResolveService<MyService>())
{
    var response = service.Get(new MyRequest { ... });
}
```

From inside a custom user session:

```
using (var service = authService.ResolveService<MyService>())
{
    var response = service.Get(new MyRequest { ... });
}
```

From outside of ServiceStack:

```
using (var service = HostContext.ResolveService<MyService>())
{
    var response = service.Get(new MyRequest { ... });
}
```

### ServiceStack Services are just normal Dependencies

Since Services in ServiceStack are just like any other IOC dependency, the implementation of [ResolveService](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack/HostContext.cs#L322) simply resolves the Service from ServiceStack's IOC and injects the current Request, i.e:

```
public static T ResolveService<T>(HttpContextBase httpCtx=null) 
    where T : class, IRequiresRequest
{
    var service = AssertAppHost().Container.Resolve<T>();
    if (service == null) return null;
    service.Request = httpCtx != null 
        ? httpCtx.ToRequest() 
        : HttpContext.Current.ToRequest();
    return service;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response.  Yeah, works a treat.  I'm not sure why I was getting raw json content returned before.  Perhaps I wasn't using ResolveService<MyService>.

Comment: @Drammy I'm assuming you were calling the service through HTTP, e.g. using the JsonServiceClient.

Comment: I've worked out what I was doing wrong - I was calling executing Get on a service but passing in a CachedRequest object expecting to hit the cache where possible.  I was therefore getting a CompressedResult back.  How should I call a resolve a service with a view to executing a method that uses the cache?